# Calculating metrics (e.g. SSIM) for multi-input multi-output Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model having 3 inputs and 2 outputs as follows

```
     _________  
a --|         |--- x
b --|  Model  |--- y
c --|_________|
```

Is there a way to compile the model and calculate metrics as structural similarity (SSIM) between specific input and output (e.g. input 'a' and output 'x)'?

```
model = keras.Model([a, b, c], [x, y])
model.compile(optimizer='adam' 
                , loss = 'mse'
                , metrics=[ssim, None])
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with multi-output models, you can pass a `dict` to the metrics arg of `compile`. Where, you `dict` should have output names as keys, and the required metrics as values.

From [TensorFlow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#compile)

...To specify different metrics for different outputs of a multi-output model, you could also pass a dictionary, such as metrics={'output_a': 'accuracy', 'output_b': ['accuracy', 'mse']}. You can also pass a list to specify a metric or a list of metrics for each output, such as metrics=[['accuracy'], ['accuracy', 'mse']] or metrics=['accuracy', ['accuracy', 'mse']] ...

Comment: So can I specify which input and output to be used for calculating custom metrics? I need to calculate SSIM between a specific input image and specific output